# Why is Parcel build creating an import that fails when I try to execute the built module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, bundling-and-minification, parcel

### Preamble

I'm very new to parcel and using bundlers so I could be doing something completely wrong.

I followed the guidance provided at [Building a library with Parcel](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/) since I am trying to bundle the server-side code which will be executed by node.js

My package.json contains the following(removed uneccessary details):

```
{
  "source":"bin/server.js",
  "module":"dist/server.js"
  "scripts":{
    "build": "parcel build"
  }
  "type":"module"
}
```

### Main Problem

When I build my application with npm rum build it generates everything just fine, no errors are thrown and it only takes about 2 seconds.

Then when I try to run the application with "node .\bin\server.js" it throws the following error.

> import {exit as $a7IyA$exit, on as $a7IyA$on} from "process";
> ------------------------------^^--------------------------------------------------
> SyntaxError: The requested module 'process' does not provide an export named 'on'

For additional context, the application does run as expected before I bundle with parcel and the server.js file does include the following as the first import (where error is thrown).

```
import {exit as $a7IyA$exit, on as $a7IyA$on} from "process";
```

#### Update:

After reviewing the [Targets](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/) documentation, this does make me more confident that Parcel can be used for backend bundling and I tried updating my package.json to the following:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "server": {
      "source": "bin/server.js",
      "context": "node",
      "distDir": "./dist",
      "includeNodeModules": true,
      "outputFormat": "esmodule"
     }
  },
  "scripts":{
    "build": "parcel build"
  }
  "type":"module"
}
```

This did get me further, but I'm now getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: $2az4q$relative is not defined

Comment: Why would you bundle backend code with a frontend bundler?

Comment: Great question. I didn't know there was a difference. What do you recommend as a backend bundler? I've been trying to research and understand bundling and everything led me to the main ones like webpack and parcel. It did seem that parcel allows for bundling non-web based applications though and can target node execution.